# Google Chrome would like to control this computer using Accessibility

Tags: macos, security, google-chrome, accessibility

I installed LastPass and on restarting Chrome got a notification similar to this: https://superuser.com/questions/657015/google-software-update-would-like-to-control-this-computer-what, except it was Google Chrome that wanted to control the computer instead of Google Software Update.

It might not have been related to the LastPass install and might have just been a coincidence and just happened to be the first time I restarted Chrome.

Any ideas on what might have prompted this request?

[image]

Chrome 32.0.1700.102

Mac OS X: 10.9.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many programs use Applescript to automate GUI functions, such as moving and clicking the mouse, but this functionality requires that the accessibility options are enabled.  According to their [support documents](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=275), LastPass is one such program that requires enabling access for assistive devices.

As a result, I wouldn't worry about the request.  As you suspected, it is probably LastPass, and everything is working normally.

If you want to know more about GUI Applescripting, check this out:

http://www.macosautomation.com/mavericks/guiscripting/index.html

Answer (score 2):

[This LastPass Support page](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=5435) indicates that this is expected and explains your various options:

> Chrome now requires that we ask users for permission to communicate
>   with our new native messaging host.
>
> So, if LastPass does not detect the binary component the first time
>   that you click on the LastPass button, we prompt you for permission.
>
> If you:
>
> - Click deny, LastPass will never prompt again
> - Click accept, LastPass will pop a confirm box stating that if you have not done so yet, you will need to run the universal installer to
>     install the binary component
>
> Then:
>
> - if you click OK, we redirect to the binary component which downloads in the browser.
> - if you click Cancel, then we do not download the binary installer.